# how to deploy code form bitbucket to amaozn EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket

I have created a laravel application and now i have push my code to a staging server.

In my amazon AWS account I have created an EC2 server, simple way to do this, and find it confusing.
I want to run this project on server.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: On server install git `sudo apt-get install -y git` (for example on ubuntu) when finished, clone the repo into server.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, Tomcat, or WARs? Isn't Laravel a PHP framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use startup script on your EC2.

Your startup script should do the following steps:

1-Install requirement software or services in the new machine.

2-Download or clone latest your app code from git and build it if necessary.

3-Download other assets or software or data from the S3 bucket.(Java, Tomcat, or WARs)

4-Start and configure services.

Answer (score 0):

You should strongly consider using the [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) service to manage the deployment of code on your instance.

It is easy to setup, and the service itself is free; you pay for instance usage only.